# C code skipping if else statement and going straight to else?

Tags: c, if-statement

Stuck on the easiest part of my coursework, writing code that requires you to specify a number of elements to use (which must be either one or two). When I input 1, it prints the correct thing. When I input 2, it prints what is under the else statement. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int nElements;
    double element1, element2;

    printf("\n Input number of flow elements to use (1 or 2): ");
    scanf("%lf", &nElements);

    if (nElements == '1') {

        printf("\n Specify type of element (1 for freestream, 2 for source, 3 for vortex): ");
        scanf("%lf", &element1);

    } else
    if (nElements == '2') {

        printf("\n Specify type of element (1 for freestream, 2 for source, 3 for vortex): ");
        scanf("%lf", &element1);    

        printf("\n Specify second type of element (1 for freestream, 2 for source, 3 for vortex): ");
        scanf("%lf", &element2);

    } else {

        printf("\n ERROR Number of flow elements must be one or two, try again");

    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%lf",&nElements);` ==> `scanf("%d",&nElements);` Also `if(nElements=='1')` will be checking the number you entered again the (typically ASCII) value of the character `'1'` which is `49`.

Comment: .. and `nElements == '1'` -> `nElements == 1`

Comment: Enable _all_ compiler warnings which should have warned about `int nElements;  scanf("%lf",&nElements);`.  That saves you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems

1. as @Weather Vane pointed out your scanf format is incorrect
2. scanf converts the input string to a number so you should check for 1 or 2: not '1' or '2'

If you really want to check for '1' or '2' then you have to input 49 or 50 respectively (assuming ASCII)